# O que significam exatamente "linkabilidade" (linkability) e "rastreabilidade" (traceability) no contexto de redes de tráfego privado?

Tags: segurança, redes, tor

O [artigo de design do Tor](http://www.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a465464.pdf) diz:

> "Clientes preocupados com ***linkabilidade*** deveriam rotacionar circuitos com mais frequência do que aqueles preocupados com ***rastreabilidade***."

Estes parecem ser termos precisos. O que querem dizer formalmente?

Answer (score 1):

Olá, vou fazer alguns comentários que acredito que possam lhe ajudar a entender melhor os termos com base nos meus estudos do CCNA, mas não posso garantir 100% de que não estou me equivocando.

No meu ponto de vista, dentro do contexto da frase apresentada, **linkabilidade** significa "possuir várias conexões". Já **rastreabilidade** significa "possuir o controle sobre as conexões existentes".

**Dessa forma:**

> "Clientes preocupados em possuir vários pontos de conexão deveriam rotacionar (utilizar protocolos de roteamento para criar uma teia de conexões) circuitos com mais frequência do que aqueles preocupados em possuir o controle sobre as conexões existentes".

**Lógica da frase:**

Quanto menos saltos um pacote executa em uma rede (saltos significam o número de roteadores ao qual o pacote passa antes de chegar ao seu destino), mais fácil fica fazer a detecção / previsão com precisão da rota que este pacote tomou. Logo, quanto menos pontos de conexão uma rede possuir, mais fácil será administra-la (possuir o controle do tráfego da mesma).

Obs: Presumo que esta frase foi retirada de um contexto que utiliza protocolos de roteamento dinâmicos, como EIGRP ou OSPF, onde o endereço do próximo salto é calculado com base em critérios específicos do protocolo e, sendo assim, a rota que os pacotes tomam para chegar ao seu destino varia.

Comment: Espero ter ajudado, qualquer dúvida me avisa!

Comment: Então, na verdade, para o caso do Tor, esses termos tem a ver com alguma garantia de segurança. Quer dizer, estou passando meu tráfego pela rede Tor com o objetivo de dar privacidade a algum aspecto do meu tráfego. Acho que linkabilidade e rastreabilidade, nesse contexto, são garantias diferentes, mas não sei como diferem. Pelo nome, imagino que "rastreabilidade" tenha a ver com encontrarem de que máquina (a minha) está vindo um certo pacote, mas acho que o termo tem um significado específico na literatura, cuja definição não encontro.